# Is there any issue/difference using literal data types

Tags: .net, vb.net, declaration, type-inference, literals

Is there any difference between:

```
Dim Str As String
Dim Int As Integer
Dim Lng As Long
Dim Sng As Single
Dim Dbl As Double
Dim Dec As Decimal
```

and

```
Dim Str$
Dim Int%
Dim Lng&
Dim Sng!
Dim Dbl#
Dim Dec@
```

Can I use abbreviations without problems?

Comment: If you like these abbreviations in VB, then you should look at the programming language APL - you'll love it. Here's an example - `life←{↑1 ⍵∨.∧3 4=+/,¯1 0 1∘.⊖¯1 0 1∘.⌽⊂⍵}`. It certainly makes coding clearer when succinct symbols are used. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

The only problem is code readability and maintainability.  Another programmer who is not familiar with the type suffixes will not be able to easily maintain your code.

Comment: I don't think it's difficult to know what suffixes means (for programmers) becouse visual studio gives you full name declaration when you move the mouse over the variable. P.S. thanks for the link (I wasn't able to find it)

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that. Those abbreviations are relics from the past. They have been around since the time of Basic. It hurts the readability of your code. Because there is IntelliSense you don't lose time typing the non-abbreviated code. If you really want to abbreviate, let the compiler pick the type like this:

```
dim str = "my string"
```

(for example).

For this to work, the [Option Infer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) must be active

Comment: This answer also illustrates the preferred method of declare and initialise in one statement (guideline 5 at [How to: Create a New Variable (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2z809s7.aspx). Note that using Option Infer On means literal type characters ([Type Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx)) may be needed on the the value, e.g. `Dim amount = 2.34D`, so that the compiler correctly infers the variable `amount` as a decimal, but the `D` would have been needed anyway with Option Strict On.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference whatsoever. See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzy06xhf.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the details of these.

These are a carryover from previous versions of Visual Basic and have (rightly) fallen out of general use, so you should try and avoid using these.

Also - it can get confusing (maybe not to you, but definitely to other people looking at your code) because all of those characters have other meanings:

- `$` String Interpolation character in VS2015
- `&` String concatenation
- `!` Field shortcut operator
- `#` Code Region

And For anyone familiar with C#:

- `%` Modulus operator in C#
- `@` String literal in C#

Note: As long as you have `Option Infer On` (and always make sure you have `Option Strict On`) - In a lot of cases you don't need to define the type, because this is correctly *inferred*:

```
Dim a = CalculateSum(1, 2)
```

In this case `CalculateSum` returns an `Integer`, so `a` is declared as an Integer.

Comment: I don't think this is a real problem, but thank you for pointing it.